# Error "ORDER_BILLING_DETAILS_COUNTRY_DYNAMIC_NOT_ALLOWED" - Functionality not available for your account

Tags: php, laravel, 2checkout

I am encountering an issue with my laravel application related to the error code "ORDER_BILLING_DETAILS_COUNTRY_DYNAMIC_NOT_ALLOWED," and the accompanying message suggests that the functionality is not available for my account, when integrate 2checkout order api. I'm seeking assistance in understanding and resolving this issue.

I expect the code to successfully create an order via API. Upon execution, the order should be processed without errors, and relevant information should be stored in the system.

Comment: Seems that this would be a better question to ask `2checkout`'s support?